# How to download a specific number of photos (not the entire post) using instaloader

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram

I'm using an api for instagram called instaloader. I'm trying to download 25 pictures from each profile in an array. I tried using get_posts

```
for post in profile.get_posts():

    #download posts
        L.download_post(post, target=data_path/p_name)
```

but this downloads the picture along with all the comments and metadata. I only want to download the pictures because the instagram accounts I'm scraping have too many comments (getting comments isn't the point anyway).

I saw something called download_pic but I have no idea how to use it. I tried using it in my code below and got an error that said "url is not defined".

```
 profile_names = ["kyliejenner", "justinbieber", "instagram"]

 for p_name in profile_names:

      profile = Profile.from_username(L.context, p_name)

      L.download_pic(data_path/p_name, url, mtime, filename_suffix=None, _attempt=1)
```

Could someone explain to me how to use download_pic (if that's what I'm supposed to be using to only download photo's/videos) and maybe send me to a reliable tutorial?

Comment: where do you have `url = "http://..."` ? It seems you don't have it - so you get your error `"url is not defined"`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jliv3/PycharmProjects/instagram_crawler/venv/Ig_Crawler.py", line 18, in <module>
    L.download_pic(data_path/p_name, url, mtime, filename_suffix=None, _attempt=1)
NameError: name 'url' is not defined

Comment: The url is supposed to be the post url, but I have no idea how to get it. I looked through their documentation about the api and it's not shown how to achieve this step by step

Comment: I would expect that you have to first download post to get urls for images.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for exacly the same thing for some time and I finally found solution:

```
L.download_pic(FILENAME, POST.url, POST.date_utc)
```

POST object you can get using e.g. Post.from_shortcode()
POST.url will give you the link for first image in post
POST.date_utc will just grab the date and time from the post (without mtime entered you are not able to download it)

This will download just the picture into folder you want to.